# Python: Excel Analysis Method

Tags: python, excel, data-analysis

I have a list of column/row numbers in a sperate excel sheet that are random. I need to use these column numbers to extract information from an another excel sheet. I could do this manually, yet I have about 35000 column numbers. Therefore, I was wondering if I can get any help here to automate this process. Anyway we can do this in python using pandas or numpy?

As shown in the scenario, I need use the information available in Sheet 1 (Column/Row Numbers, i.e., A1, B2, B3) to select the information in the sheet 2.

Scenario:

**Sheet 1**

| Column A |
| --- |
| A2 |
| B2 |
| B3 |

**Sheet 2**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Cat |
| Bat | Dog |

Comment: You can do this using the INDIRECT formula, no need for pandas.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Whenever I write the INDIRECT formula such as, =INDIRECT("A1"), the output  is "A2" (referring to Sheet1 in above question). How can I parse that list of column/row numbers available in Sheet1 into the INDIRECT FORMULA so I don't have to type each cell number manually since I have 35,000? I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!"&A1)`